# Can i have groups for attributes in HDF5 python?

Tags: python, attributes, metadata, hdf5

I am currently working with multiple levels of data. Lets say Data levels (DL)
DL1 -> DL2 -> DL3.

For each of the data processing, There are different attributes (these are at root levels) for each of the processing steps. These attributes might be git versions, the processing code version, etc etc.

When i am at DL2, i want to save the attributes from DL1 and group it under lets say ['DL1_attribute'] and then add the DL2 attribute on top of this. Since i have multiple processing steps, grouping would be beneficial. Can i have nested grouped attributes at root level?
I have seen few examples where the attributes are not nested but attributes are set for the defined nested datasets that are already present in the hdf5.

> For example, for DL1 i have the h5 structure as

```
lvl1_file['Data/dataset1'] = somedataset     
lvl1_file['Data/dataset2'] = someotherdataset
```

> and attributes as

```
lvl1_file.attrs['lvl1_git_branch'] ='temp_testing'    
lvl1_file.attrs['l1tol2_version'] = '2.1a'    
lvl1_fiel.attrs['aux_file_version'] = '10.1'
```

> Now at lvl2 i want to store the attributes as

```
lvl2_file.attrs['l1attrs/lvl1_git_branch']='temp_testing'  
lvl2_file.attrs['l1attrs/l1tol2_version']='2.1a'    
lvl2_file.attrs['l1attrs/aux_file_version'] = '10.1'
```

> and additionally add new attributes from lvl2.

```
lvl2_file.attrs['l2attrs/lvl2_git_branch']='dev'
lvl2_file.attrs['l2attrs/l2tol3_version']='3.0a'
```

Or if i could do a nested dictionary that would be great too,.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Each object (dataset or group) saves its attributes independently. So, you can assign an attribute named `DL1_attribute` to Group DL1 and another attribute named `DS1_attribute` to Dataset DS1. You can also have the same attribute name assigned with different values to different objects. E.g., you could have `Date Created` on every object, each with a different date. You cannot "nest" attributes (assign an attribute to an attribute). Why would you want to do that?